# Multiple meditation practices

Tags: theravada, meditation, tibetan-buddhism

Would there be a conflict if I were to practice meditation from various schools? For instance mahasi insight meditation, Tibetan Samantha meditation, as long as the skills are kept separate?

Answer (score 2):

Probably fine at the exploratory stage. But once you've found the method most suitable to your own development and growth, then it'd be best to dive deep into just that single method. Sorta like pursuing a college degree or graduate degrees, one would take some general courses in his freshman and sophomore years, but then would have to focus on courses specific to their major in junior and senior years.

Answer (score 1):

In the immortals words of Ron Swanson - "Don't half ass two things; whole ass one thing".  Why scatter your attention and your efforts?  Pick one and follow it wholeheartedly.  Being able to make that commitment alone will be more beneficial than any advantage pursuing multiple paths might bring.

Answer (score 0):

While both of the techniques mentioned will ultimately bring limited results if 'mastered', there is no conflict or detriment for a newbie to practice both.